# Uri from Filepath returns false EncodedPath

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a Uri of a File that the User can pick with a `FilePicker`.
I can make an intent with this Uri and Google Sheets opens the file successfully.

I now get the Path of the `pickedUri` and create a new Uri with it and try to open it. This does not work.

If I compare the paths of the URIs, they are identical but if I compare the encoded Paths then they don't match.

```
filepath = pickedUri.getPath();
Uri testUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
```

and

```
filepath = pickedUri.getPath();
Uri testUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filepath);
```

Comment: Why do you wanna create a new uri? Use the first one. All your trying is false.

Comment: I want to create a duplicate of that Uri for testing purposes. In the end I need to let the user pick a file and then depending on the result of a qr code a different file that's named similar to the first one has to be opened. So I want to get the path of the first Uri then slightly change it and create another Uri with it.

Comment: That will not go for most of the uris are not decodable to a file system path and if you could you would have no access to that path. And just creating another uri makes no sense. What do you want to do with the file behind the new uri?

Comment: I need to make an intent with the new file and open it in Google Sheets

Comment: If you have a new file and you want to serve it then you have to use your own file provider. You cannot just change the file name of a valid uri and expect that the provider will serve that other file. Use FileProvider class to serve your file.